# problema com cópia oculta no phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Galera estou tentando enviar vários e-mails com o phpmailer, meus destinatários estão recebendo eles, porém para evitar que eles vejam para quem mais eu enviei os e-mail, eu utilizei a seguinte função:

```
$email->AddBCC($resultado_nome->email, $resultado_nome->nome);
```

O problema e que eles recebem o email com o seguinte:

```
undisclosed-recipients:;
```

Bom atualmente eu passo da seguinte forma:

```
// Define os destinatário(s)
$consulta_nome = $mysqli->query("select * from cadastro");
while ($resultado_nome = mysqli_fetch_object($consulta_nome)) {


   // Destinatório e cópia oculta
   $email->AddBCC($resultado_nome->email, $resultado_nome->nome);

   // Iremos enviar o email no formato HTML
   $email->IsHTML(true);

   // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
   $email->Subject = "Nova email";
   $email->Body = "emai";

   // Envia o e-mail
   $email->Send();
}
```

Esta errado? Dessa forma envia um e-mail para todo mundo da minha lista de cadastro

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece pois todos os destinatários estão escondidos.

Veja o [changelog v1.7 2003](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/104359d99345b3705dabb890bb5bc7450c795f3d/changelog.md#version-170-mon-jun-20-2003):

> Adds "To: undisclosed-recipients:;" when all recipients are hidden (BCC)
>
> [pt-br] *Adiciona "To: undisclosed-recipients:;" quando todos os destinatários estão escondidos (BCC)*

Você pode ver como isso é tratado no código-fonte aqui também:

- [class.phpmailer.php#1254](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/cb8bde329a79ae45ee7dce3aafeb374f35c542cc/class.phpmailer.php#L1254)
- [class.phpmailer.php#1946](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/cb8bde329a79ae45ee7dce3aafeb374f35c542cc/class.phpmailer.php#L1946)

Para evitar isso, você pode adicionar ao "To" um email seu (ex.: noreply@meudominio.com), ou enviar um email por vez para cada destinatário, mas certamente isso não é um 'problema'. Se optar por mudar, será por 'estética' mesmo.

Comment: o problema e que criei uma pagina onde verifico todos os cadastro do meu sistema e mando um e-mail. Como faço para mandar 1 e-mail de cada vez?

Comment: @HugoBorges faça um `for` nessa lista de emails e vá disparando os emails, mas não é a melhor alternativa: geralmente há um limite diário de emails que você pode disparar e consome bem mais recursos dessa maneira. Via de regra, o que está acontecendo com você não é um problema, é só questão de estética mesmo. Preferiria a solução de um email no "To". Se a resposta lhe ajudou a esclarecer, dê um voto. Se era o que você queria saber, marque como resposta. Obrigado!